# Why does prisma give an internal error while creating new record?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, plumatic-schema, prisma-binding

I am trying to create a new record, although in my response I receive the following error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck4rzmu0f065x0824h90npxcl",
      "path": [
        "createOrder"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck4rzmu0f065x0824h90npxcl"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It will be extremely difficult for anyone to assist with your query without some further information. This information appears to be coming back from the HTTP request, does the console (or server logs) that the server is running in have different output?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your prisma server and database logs. If you are running docker on a local development environment you can use `docker logs CONTAINER` or `docker-compose logs` to search for the error message.

Here you can find more information on how to manage the docker environment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/deployment-environments/docker-rty1/